# How to measure an elements width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am having an annoying bug that I forgot why it happens:

I have an ordinary html list

```
<ul> <li>Some text</li> <li>Another Text </li> <li>text</li> <li>another one</li> </ul>
```

and I am trying to measure each li width

I was trying to write this jQuery code:

```
for (var i=0; i++; i <4)
{
   $("ul li")[i].width();
}
```

but somehow that doesn't work - what am I doing wrong in this sentence `$("ul li")[i].width();` ?

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: what is it that you are expecting?

Comment: I want to check the width of each <li> element - assuming each one has different text size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul li').each(function()
{
    $(this).width();
});
```

This is far more simple to walk over a set of elements with the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
     /*width*/
     console.log( $(this).width());
     /*width+padding*/
     console.log( $(this).outerWidth(true));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For use in a custom loop, you need to use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method (*and you should cache the list of element, instead of re-searching for all of them*)

```
var li_elements = $("ul li");
for(var i=0, len = li_elements.length; i<len; i++) {
  var elementWidth = li_elements.eq(i).width();
   // do what you need with it..
}
```

or you can use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to iterate over the list

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
   var elementWidth = $(this).width();
   // do what you need with it..
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an indexer with a jquery object, you get the DOM elements.

try:

```
var $items = $("ul li");
for (var i=0; i < 4; i++)
{
   $items.eq(i).width();
}
```

Comment: why extract the dom element and rebuild it ... you can use the built-in method `.eq()`

Answer (score 1):

`$("ul li")[i]` is returning you a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Use:

```
var elements = $("ul li");
elements.each(function(){
    //do something with $(this).width()
});
```

Note also, using the selector once outside the loop and them iterating over it, rather than repeating the selection every time.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing array items on jQuery objects will return you the actual DOM object, not the one wrapped with jQuery's sugar. Use `$(...).eq(0).width()` instead.

Also, you can just use the `each()` method to iterate over all the items instead of a `for` loop, which is much easier, nicer-looking and elegant IMHO.